# Powershell Remoting: access domain resources

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a problem running my PS cmdlet remotely. Cmdlet is written on C# and performs connection to SQL Server database using Windows Auth.
When I run it from the remote machine (machine B) - everything is good, but when I try to run it remotely (from machine A) - it cannot connect to the database. In both cases I run it under the same domain account (Task Manager also shows that both powereshell.exe and wsmprovhost.exe(remote) on machine B use the same account).

Is there anything special I should configure setting up PSSession?

Comment: You should update your original post to include the code you're running and details on and how it fails, for instance, do you get any error messages?

Comment: I can't share the code, just because the callstack is very huge and it doesn't make a lot of sense (and it is intellectual property, I can't share it). Code itself is fine, otherwise it wouldn't work from a remote machine directly. This code doesn't work ONLY when running remotely. And the issue is somewhere around **impersonation in wsmprovhost.exe**

Comment: So no errors local and nothing in the logs of the target machine?

Comment: Yes, it cannot just authenticate to SQL Server due to incorrect impersonation (even though Task Manager says that "remote process" is running under correct account

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the error message ? And yes there are some pre-configurations for setting up PSSession I suggest that you take a look at the links below:

https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/
https://theitbros.com/run-powershell-script-on-remote-computer/

Comment: Sorry, you may misunderstood me. The PSSession itself works fine, I can execute  different commands over it. The problem start when I try to execute a specific cmdlet that requires to run under a specific domain account (impersonation). This C# written cmdlet authenticates to SQL Server database using Windows Auth

Comment: Also, this may help to better understand the problem: when I run this cmdlet from Azure DevOps "PowerShell on Target Machines" task of v2 - it works fine (but only with v2, all other versions don't work)